# Eclipse GEF Shapes Look and Feel

Tags: eclipse-gef

I am creating a gef editor for bpmn2 notations. I am able to create figures in editors, but i am lacking in look and feel of the shapes but i tried applying patterns for draw2d figures but its not same as expected one. Please tell any samples or links for gef shapes with good look and feel.

Comment: Flagging this question as off-topic because it is unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

GEF figures are draw2d figures and have no "look and feel" whatsoever. If you want the figures to look differently, you have to create them differently - setting borders, colors, linestyles, etc.